# How to redirect URLs so that they are all handled by the same PHP page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I know that there are many questions about this subject, but the questions, and even more the answers are kind of confusing me.

What I want to do:
I want to have an internet page, wich, depending on the URL, shows different content. However, in the backend, all pages are handled by one central PHP page.

In other words:

www.example.com/

www.example.com/AboutUs

www.example.com/Contact

should all be handled by a single .php script, but in such a way that in the browser of the users the URLS are kept intact.

Now, is this done with .htaccess rewriting or not? And how?

Answer (score 3):

`.htaccess` using Rewrite would be the best approach for this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In your `index.php` you can use the value of `$_GET['uri']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine which functionality is being requested.

If you only want your controller script to handle requests for files and directories that don't already exist, you can do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I understand it correctly, it changes http://www.example.com/something to http://www.example.com/index.php?url=something.  Is that right? And is it invisible to the people browsing the page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this by adding mod_rewrite rules to your .htaccess file. Here is an article with more detailed information: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/.

It may not help your confusion, but it will at least teach you the proper syntax. Basically, mod_rewrite takes the "clean" URL given in the browser, decodes it using a regular expression, then discretely passes the matches from the regular expression as GET variables.

In other words: mod_rewrite takes "example.com/AboutUs", reads the URL, and serves up whatever would be on the page "example.com/index.php?page=AboutUs" without showing users the actual GET-variable-ridden URL.